# Can you make the numbers? My code outputs correct but isn't accepted?

Tags: php, algorithm

The question I'm working on is:

> You are given an array representing the number of 0s, 1s, 2s, ..., 9s you have. The function will look like:
>
> can_build([#0s, #1s, #2s, ..., #9s], [num1, num2, ...])
>
> Write a function that returns true if you can build the following
> numbers using only the digits you have.
>
> **Example:**
>
> canBuild([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3]) ➞ false

I basically wrote:

```
function canBuild($digits, $arr) {

    if(array_unique($digits) === 0 && $arr === []) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($arr === [] && array_unique($digits) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = [];
    $test = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $test[$i] = str_split($arr[$i]);
    }

    $digit = array_unique($digits);

    $results = [];

    foreach($test as $k => $v) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($test[$k]); $j++) {
            if(in_array($v[$j], $digit)) {
                array_push($results, "true");
            } else {
                array_push($results, "false");
            }
        }
    }


    if(array_unique($results) === "true") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

canBuild([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 80, 0]); // false
```

But for some reason I keep getting: **"CanBuildNumbersUsingDigits tests FAILED: Failed asserting that false is true.""** Can anyone see something wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: You have to take digit counts into consideration and keep consuming them before going for next numbers.

Comment: @nice_dev: Thank you, though I'm not following you. Can you explain in slightly more detail? Thanks! All the input I've given it has returned correctly?

Comment: What output do you expect for `canBuild([0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [33,33])`?

Comment: It returns false .. which I assume is right unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: What should be the expected output? Should it be true or false? I am not asking what your code returns

Comment: Expected output should be `false` - though I just realized the example posted above is wrong, and is wrong on the site. I updated it show a right example. Here is a link to the quesiton: https://edabit.com/challenge/FsueCtqQ25PmPp9Sg - So I'm wondering if there is something wrong with their test or is my code messed up?

Comment: Ok. so a couple of mistakes. Before diving into logic, can you tell me whether `array_unique($digits) !== 0` and `array_unique($results) === "true"` are correct since you are doing strict comparisons?

Comment: Yes they're correct in this instance. If `array_unique($digits) !== 0` then we know the input array is not just [0, 0, 0]? And in the second case if there is `false` in `$results` we know there is a integer which is not in the input array? I assume strict comparison is OK in this context?

Comment: [Are you sure](https://3v4l.org/HZuR6)?

Comment: Just check solutions tab there. I have made a correct submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
array_unique($results) === "true"
```

and

```
array_unique($digits) !== 0
```

are semantically incorrect. `array_unique()` would return a value of type *array* which can never be equal to any scalar value or string since you are doing a strict comparison.

Moreover, your code doesn't account for count of digits but rather checks if count of a digit is present in the array.

---

**Solution:**

To solve this problem, you just have to loop over the `$arr` array of numbers, `str_split` them into individual characters(like you did) and keep decrementing these string digits from actual count of each digit given in `$digits`. If any digit count happens to be less than zero, meaning we don't have that much count of that digit, we return `false` since we can't *form* that number. If all is well, we return `true` in the end.

```
function canBuild($digits, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $num){
        $chars = str_split($num);
        foreach($chars as $char){
            $digits[intval($char)]--;
            if($digits[intval($char)] < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```